# How do I resend invitation to a user using devise invitable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-invitable

I have devise invitable gem
Hooked up in my app as well as devise.

Everything working fine. When I create new user, they are saved in database and mailer sends email an email address. User clicks on email, sets password and then is logged in.

But sometimes these users lose their email or rather can’t find it in their email inbox. I’d like to have a resend invite button on the users index page.

When user clicks resend, I want the invites user to get another email sent to them.

Had anyone successfully accomplished this with devise invitable? If so, can you share how?

Comment: How do I resend it is the question? How do I create a resend button? What code goes into this?

Comment: The views generated to not appear to have resend buttons anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The gem adds a `resend_invitation` configuration parameter on your invitable-enabled model. From the docs:

> `resend_invitation`: resend invitation if user with invited status is invited again. Enabled by default.

So, calling `.invite!` again on a record that's marked as invited will do the trick for you.

Comment: This happens to be where I'm getting thrown off.

I have this in my routes.rb

```
  devise_scope :admin do
    get '/admin/invitation/resend/:id', to: 'invitations#resend', as: 'admin_invitation_resend'
  end
```
in my view
```
        <%= link_to "resend", admin_invitation_resend_path(admin), class: "dropdown-item" %>
```
and in invitations_controller.rb
```
   def resend
     @admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
     @admin.invite!
   end
```
and the index will load, but when I click resend button, I get: 

Routing Error: uninitialized constant InvitationsController